# Sub Sorting in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, oracle10g

I have a demographics database where I have a list of population numbers per continent, country, state and city. I have now added a rank column to this table which I need to update. However the ranking needs to happen at a state level. So there will be a rank 1..N for each city within a state. The ranking will then again begin from 1..N for another state.

(Note: City names can be duplicate.. i.e. a city might exist in more than one state but there will be 2 different rows for it if that happens. The PK is CONTINENT,CNTRY,STATE).

I've been trying all sorts of select subqueries and RANK function variations but just cant get my head round it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, can you add some more information about your table, data and expected output? it would really help us to understand it better...

Comment: thanks deepak... just got what i was looking for in the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a RANK per state you need PARTITION BY:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTINENT, CNTRY, STATE ORDER BY poulation DESC)
```

If there's a city twice with a state you might switch to ROW_NUMBER instead.

And because this is a small table you might consider calculating the rank dynamically within a View instead of potentially updating a large number of rows whenever there's an update/insert.

Comment: thanks ! that has worked... much appreciated. The tip for using the view also makes sense.